# Clearing sessionStorage when browser crashed

Tags: javascript, html

In my application I am using `sessionStorage` to save data at client side. My application working fine but I want to implement a handling of clearing `sessionStorage` when browser window got crashed.
How can I clear the `sessionStorage` when window crashed.

Comment: interesting... when the browser crashes - it preserves sessionStorage when rebooted?

Comment: yes it does preserves the sessionStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have acheived this by implementing below code into my index.html file:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      sessionStorage.setItem('good_exit', 'pending');
      setInterval(function () {
         sessionStorage.setItem('time_before_crash', new Date().toString());
      }, 1000);
   });

   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
      sessionStorage.setItem('good_exit', 'true');
   });

   if(sessionStorage.getItem('good_exit') &&
      sessionStorage.getItem('good_exit') !== 'true') {
      /*
         insert crash logging code here
     */
      alert('Hey, welcome back from your crash, looks like you crashed on: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('time_before_crash'));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the *browser* doesn't erase all sessionStogare **on reboot** since that's clearly a new browsing instance...

but **what you could do** in your application is to always firstly clear any eventual residues using

```
sessionStorage.clear(); // on application restart clear any eventual residues

// Your program logic here
```

Here's a basic test example:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wogowas/3/edit?html,js,output)**

```js
// 1. let's clear it
sessionStorage.clear();

// 2. Let's try to store a value
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  sessionStorage.test = "TEST";
  document.body.textContent = sessionStorage.test;
});

// 3. let's try to crash Chrome (copy this into a tab addressbar)
// chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz

// 4. on browser RESTORE we should see the button, not the stored value
if(sessionStorage.test) document.body.textContent = sessionStorage.test;
```

```html
<button>CLICK TO STORE</button>
```